# How do I screen scrape a website and get data within div?

Tags: php, curl, screen-scraping

How can I screen scrape a website using cURL and show the data within a specific div?

Comment: *(suggestion)* Try to do it with DOM and XPath instead.

Answer (score 6):

Download the page using cURL (There are a lot of [examples](http://www.php.net/manual/en/curl.examples-basic.php) in the documentation). Then use a DOM Parser, for example [Simple HTML DOM](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) or PHPs [DOM](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) to extract the value from the div element.

Comment: Please comment when downvoting to give me the chance to correct or otherwise improve my answer.

Answer (score 0):

After downloading with cURL use [XPath](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath) to select the div and extract the content.

Answer (score -1):

Fetch the website content using a cURL GET request.  There's a code sample on the [`curl_exec` manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-exec.php).

Use a regular expression to search for the data you need.  There's a code sample on the [`preg_match` manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php), but you'll need to do some reading up on [regular expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expressions) to be able to build the pattern you need.  As [Yacoby](https://stackoverflow.com/users/118145/yacoby) mentioned which I hadn't thought of, a better idea may be to examine the DOM of the HTML page using PHP's Simple XML or DOM parser.

Output the information you've found from the regex/parser in the HTML of your page (within the required `div`.)

Comment: The <center> cannot hold ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Answer (score -1):

A possible alternative.

```
# We will store the web page in a string variable.
var string page

# Read the page into the string variable.
cat "http://www.abczyx.com/path/to/page.ext" > $page

# Output the portion in the third (3rd) instance of "<div...</div>"
stex -r -c "^<div&</div\>^3" $page
```

This code is in biterscripting. I am using the 3 as sample to extract 3rd div. If you want to extract the div that has say string "ABC", then use this command syntax.

```
stex -r -c "^<div&ABC&</div\>^" $page
```

Take a look at this script http://www.biterscripting.com/helppages/SS_ExtractTable.html . It shows how to extract an element (div, table, frame, etc.) when the elements are nested.